# Hidden folder in Recycle Bin?

Tags: windows-7, virus, malware

Even though the Recycle Bin is said to be empty, I found a folder called $RKHKXRU that contained like 5 GB of documents (e.g. "12 Professions (< random number >).doc"). After turning on show hidden files and turning off hide system files, I was able to see it. I noticed it existed when a few virus scanners (first Malwarebytes and then Panda) were scanning the Recycle Bin. I thought it was empty but apparently it wasn't.

Is this a result of some sort of malware? I would think it is a clever trick to bog down scanners. Is this anything known?

Comment: There isn’t enough information.  VirusTotal might help.  Uploading the file(s) mighty hold clues

Comment: @Ramhound Wish I thought of it before I deleted the folder. I might be able to try to recover it using Recuva or a similar tool and then scan it. Maybe even see what was in these documents.

Comment: The files clearly were not your files so just delete them but we can’t tell if they were a false positive or not